# How to describe a process of app.run() block at latest angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Maybe `.run()` block are deprecated at latest version of AngularJS.
I need to describe a process in `.run()` block just like below.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.run(function () {
    // my process here.
};
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code. Fix it, and the run block should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run block works in latest version of AngularJS

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.run(function () {
    // my process here.
    console.log("my process here.");
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
</body>
```